# Java : recursive constructor call and stackoverflow error

Tags: java, recursion, constructor

Please help to understand why does the following code

```
public class HeapQn1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public HeapQn1() {
        new HeapQn1();
    }

    static HeapQn1 n = new HeapQn1();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

}
```

results in

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.rg.test.interview.HeapQn1.<init>(HeapQn1.java:8)
    at com.rg.test.interview.HeapQn1.<init>(HeapQn1.java:9)
    ...
```

As per my understanding the memory allocation for an object happens in the heap memory and I was expecting an OutOfMemoryError as at some point the heap memory will be full because of repetitive object creation.

On research , I came across that a java constructor is considered a method and that explained the StackOverflowError , until I read the following thread.

[When does the Constructor gets called in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567341/when-does-the-constructor-gets-called-in-java)

which says

```
3. The object is fully constructed/created when the constructor returns.
```

From what I could gather , the constructor is a method and since the heap memory is much larger than stack memory , the recursive constructor call resulted in StackOverflowError . Is this correct ?

Since no object in the give code will get completely created , will stack frame allocation for constructor actually happen ?

--edit-- 
For the duplicates pointed out , I do understand what StackoverflowError is . I have mentioned in the question "On research , I came across that a java constructor is considered a method and that explained the StackOverflowError". My question is to understand if a constructor gets a stack frame allocated just like other methods as the object creation is not complete until the constructor returns. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: you can test by setting very small heap size....

Comment: possible duplicate of [When does StackOverflowError occur?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658264/when-does-stackoverflowerror-occur)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stack-overflow-error

Comment: @Raedwald - I understand what a StackOverflowError is , my question is 1.how does why the code did not end up in OutOfMemoryError 2. is constructor a method .

Comment: I've made some empirical experiments and I've summarized them in my answer. Check it out  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever the constructor is called, its `return address` is pushed onto [the stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). As the stack is finite and smaller than the heap memory, you are getting error like `StackOverflowError` rather than `OutOfMemoryError`.

> The constructor is a method and since the heap memory is much larger than the stack memory, the recursive constructor call resulted in StackOverflowError. Is this correct ?

Yeah, your *wild* guess is completely correct. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is a method, a.k.a. a function. Every time you call it a chunk of memory is allocated to the **stack**, to store the variables of the function.

Your code creates calls to the constructor function indefenitely, allocating memory to the stack until the memory finishes.

You are obtaining a `StackOverflowError` and not an `OutOfMemoryError`, because the quantity of memory dedicated to the stack is smaller than the quantity of memory dedicated to the heap.

EDIT: I have done some test using your code. I've specified a heap memory space of 8M (`-Xms8M -Xmx8M`) and a stack memory space of 100M (`-Xss100M`). The computation result is always the error `StackOverflowError`.

Then, this could mean that **no memory is allocated to the heap in this case**. As you stated in your question:

> The object is fully constructed/created when the constructor returns.

Comment: Isn't it the other way round?

Comment: @Jagger Why are you saying that?

Comment: You wrote that the memory consumed by the stack is greater than the one consumed by the heap. I think it should be the other way round.

Comment: My english is not perfect, so it could be that I've wrote something wrong. The exception he obtained was a `StackOverflowError`, then the memory of the stack was consumed quicklier than the memory of the heap, wasn't it?

Comment: Well, technically no, because if only the stack space runs out then you cannot even say of heap allocation in this case, can you?

Comment: Are sure that the `new` operator is not allocating anything on the *heap* before the `StackOverflowError` occurs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80875/discussion-between-riccardo-cardin-and-jagger).

Answer (score 0):

You are right: the stack is much smaller than the heap, and no object will be fully created.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you said is correct, the stack space runs out before the heap space does.

Answer (score 0):

As per the java all the reference variables are stored in the stack memory space and stack memory space is smaller than heap space that's what we get stackOverFlowException.