# Does an object automatically reference a constructor during its creation?

Tags: java

I am confused about this syntax:

```
ImageTests ttpanel=new ImageTests();

 // create a JFrame to hold the test JPanel
 JFrame app = new JFrame("Image Tests");
 app.getContentPane().add(ttpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

ImageTests is another class whose constructor creates a JPanel. Therefore, does an object always references its constructors when it is not ordered to reference some other method? In short, does an unreferenced object automatically references the constructors? I have never seen this kind of syntax before.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. Basically, ttPanel is already constructed and the  app.getContentPane().add() method is just getting passed a reference to the ttPanel object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When does the Constructor gets called in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567341/when-does-the-constructor-gets-called-in-java)

Comment: *"I have never seen this kind of syntax before."* Me neither. Having two variables `ttpanel` and `ttPanel` that differ only by the upper-/lower-case of the `P` is horrendous!!! And the class names `ImageTests` vs `ImagesTests`. Yeah, I have never seen bad code that that before, either.

Comment: At first there was a mistake in the question. I have corrected it.

Comment: `new ImageTests()` and `new JFrame("Image Tests")` are both constructors. Your question remains unclear.

Comment: My question is, does an unreferenced object automatically references the constructors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A constructor is only called once in the life time of an object, it is called only when the object is created. When you use `new`.

eg.

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
```

When an object of MyClass is created the constructor of MyClass will be executed.