# Java - error: cannot find symbol - presumably scoping issue

Tags: java, object, scoping

it's my first time asking something on here, be gentle on me if I fail to consider everything. I'll try my best.

To the actual problem. I just recently started programming Java, so this will probably be something basic, although I wasn't able to figure out what the problem is by checking out similar questions.

I'd wager this error is thrown due to a scoping issue, but I can't tell for certain, or fix it even.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Artikel a = new Artikel();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    if (args.length !=8){
        System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie die folgenden Werte, getrennt mit einem ',' ein: Artikelname, Artikelnummer, Mengeneinheit, Packungsgröße, Mindestbestand, Bestellmenge, Lagerbestand, Hersteller");        
        String eingabe = scanner.next();
        String parts[] = eingabe.split(",");
        String string1 = parts[0];
        String string2 = parts[1];
        String string3 = parts[2];
        int int1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);
        int int2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[4]);
        int int3 = Integer.parseInt(parts[5]);
        int int4 = Integer.parseInt(parts[6]);
        String string4 = parts[7];

        a.Artikel(string1, string2, string3, int1, int2, int3, int4, string4);
    }
    else{
        a.Artikel(args[0], args[1], args[2], Integer.parseInt(args[3]), Integer.parseInt(args[4]), Integer.parseInt(args[5]), Integer.parseInt(args[6]), args[7]);
    }
```

That's the bit the error refers to, specifically the lines in which I try to access a.Artikel(...). Let me know if the code bit doesn't suffice.

edit:

```
public class Artikel{
private String Artikelname;
private String Artikelnr;
private String menge;
private int packgroesse;
private int mindestZahl;
private int bestell;
private int lager;
private String Hersteller;

//Defaultkonstruktor

public Artikel(){
    this.Artikelname = "Bez1";
    this.Artikelnr = "0";
    this.menge = "Beispiel";
    this.packgroesse = 0;
    this.mindestZahl = 0;
    this.bestell = 0;
    this.lager = 0;
    this.Hersteller = "Muster";
}

//Konstruktor

public Artikel(String Artikelname, String Artikelnr, String menge, int packgroesse, int mindestZahl, int bestell, int lager, String Hersteller){
    this.Artikelname = Artikelname;
    this.Artikelnr = Artikelnr;
    this.menge = menge;

    if(packgroesse < 0 ){
        System.out.println("Die Packungsgroesse kann nicht negativ sein! Der Wert wurde auf den Standardwert (10) gesetzt.");
    }
    else{
    this.packgroesse = packgroesse;
    }

    if(mindestZahl < 0 ){
        System.out.println("Der Mindestbestand kann nicht negativ sein! Der Wert wurde auf den Standardwert (30) gesetzt.");
    }
    else{
    this.mindestZahl = mindestZahl;
    }

    if(bestell < 0 ){
        System.out.println("Die Bestellmenge kann nicht negativ sein! Der Wert wurde auf den Standardwert (50) gesetzt.");
    }
    else{
    this.bestell = bestell;
    }

    if(lager < 0 ){
        System.out.println("Der Lagerbestand kann nicht negativ sein! Der Wert wurde auf den Standardwert (50) gesetzt.");
    }
    else{
    this.lager = lager;
    }

    this.Hersteller = Hersteller;
}
```

Comment: The variable `a` is an instantiated `Artikel`. What is the definition of `Artikel`? Generally either you have some setter method on the class `Artikel` that accepted the parameters or you would not instantiate in the line `Artikel a = new Articel();` (just declare it) and then in the other lines do `a = new Artikel(...)` assuming the parameters are passed to the constructor.

Comment: That actually did the trick and it seems intelligible to do it that way. 
But would you mind explaining how that makes a difference to the compiler? 
Is it not possible to initialise an object to hard coded values (standard constructor) and reassign values through an overloaded constructor?

Comment: @plc constructor are not method in java. You cannot call them like `a.Artikel()` like this. Whenever you call constructor , it creates a fresh new object.

Comment: Short answer: no. An object's constructor is only called once, at the time of instantiation [When does the Constructor get called in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567341/when-does-the-constructor-gets-called-in-java). If you wish to have default values assigned via a default constructor, you would then need to add so-called `setter` methods to update the values of the instance variables.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. All the linked post and your explanation cleared it up. It's quite confusing coming from C. Especially to make all the proper connections from structures to objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the class `Artikel` is defined such that it has a constructor that accepts the various parameters such as:

```
public class Artikel {
  ...
  public Artikel (String s1, String s2, String s3, int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4, String s4) {
   // set the various values in the instance variables
   ...
  }
}
```

then the solution based upon the code above would be something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

// CHANGE: just define
Artikel a;

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

if (args.length !=8){
    System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie die folgenden Werte, getrennt mit einem ',' ein: Artikelname, Artikelnummer, Mengeneinheit, Packungsgröße, Mindestbestand, Bestellmenge, Lagerbestand, Hersteller");        
    String eingabe = scanner.next();
    String parts[] = eingabe.split(",");
    String string1 = parts[0];
    String string2 = parts[1];
    String string3 = parts[2];
    int int1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);
    int int2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[4]);
    int int3 = Integer.parseInt(parts[5]);
    int int4 = Integer.parseInt(parts[6]);
    String string4 = parts[7];

    // CHANGE: instantiate here
    a = new Artikel(string1, string2, string3, int1, int2, int3, int4, string4);
}
else{
    // CHANGE: instantiate here
    a = new Artikel(args[0], args[1], args[2], Integer.parseInt(args[3]), Integer.parseInt(args[4]), Integer.parseInt(args[5]), Integer.parseInt(args[6]), args[7]);
}
```

It depends on how the `Artikel` class is defined, of course.

Answer (score 1):

```
Artikel a;
if (args.length != 8 ) {
    ...
    String eingabe = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] parts = eingabe.split(", *", 8); // At most 8.


    a = new Artikel(string1, string2, string3, int1, int2, int3, int4, string4);
}
else{
    a = new Artikel(args[0], args[1], args[2], Integer.parseInt(args[3]),
        Integer.parseInt(args[4]), Integer.parseInt(args[5]), Integer.parseInt(args[6]),
        args[7]);
}
```

There is the variable declaration of `a`, and filling it with a value of `new Artikel(...)`, a new object.

Also `Scanner.next()` reads one token, whereas `nextLine` an entire line.

Answer (score 1):

How about if we do like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Artikel a;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    if (args.length !=8){
        System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie die folgenden Werte, getrennt mit einem ',' ein: Artikelname, Artikelnummer, Mengeneinheit, Packungsgröße, Mindestbestand, Bestellmenge, Lagerbestand, Hersteller");        
        String eingabe = scanner.next();
        String parts[] = eingabe.split(",");
        String string1 = parts[0];
        String string2 = parts[1];
        String string3 = parts[2];
        int int1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);
        int int2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[4]);
        int int3 = Integer.parseInt(parts[5]);
        int int4 = Integer.parseInt(parts[6]);
        String string4 = parts[7];

        a = new Artikel(string1, string2, string3, int1, int2, int3, int4, string4);
    }
    else{
        a = new Artikel(args[0], args[1], args[2], Integer.parseInt(args[3]), Integer.parseInt(args[4]), Integer.parseInt(args[5]), Integer.parseInt(args[6]), args[7]);
    }
```

I think you should see how to use constructor to create object in java.
[Look here](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/constructors-in-java/)

See once you create an object using `Artikel a = new Artikel()` you cannot call constructor again and expect it to initialize the same object with new values. Also constructor is always called with new operator and it creates a fresh new object. Also constructor is not method in Java.Hence you cannot call like `a.Artikel(...)`. [Look Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061599/methods-vs-constructors-in-java)